# Linking to API available in future OS

Tags: objective-c, macos, linker

Without going into specifics and breaking NDA...

If a developer preview of OSX shows me that a certain API is now part of the AppKit where I previously had to implement the API as a category of the class how do I arrange things so something built and linked against that future SDK will still run on on the current OS.

So in an abstract sense in the current SDK for Lion I have the method `coolThing` defined in a Category of the class `NSFooBar` so I can call

`object.thing = fooBarInstance.coolThing`

However the future SDK shows me that `coolThing` is now provided by the SDK and hence my category conflicts at build time.

Can I ensure that my Application still works on Lion (where the symbol will not be available) when Im linked against the future SDK without this sort of mess.

```
if(OSVersion == Lion) {
    return myImplementation;
}
else {
    return SDKNativeImplementaion;
}
```

Which I suppose I could hide away in the Category but it seems like a bit of mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the reason you should [prefix your category methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/CreationGuidelines.html). So instead of `coolThing`, you could call it `wb_coolThing` or something like that. Your category method could check at runtime whether there is a `coolThing` method, call that if available or use your own implementation if not.

Comment: Good point. Asking the question solved it for me. I have renamed the method and placed a respondToSelector in the Category. Thanks